# How to pass template from 1 component to another

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, siblings

app.module.ts is the root module.

It has 2 child modules - 1. table.module.ts and 2. status.module.ts

Table component is a wrapper around ngx-datatable. I need to pass below template from status.component.ts to table.component.ts:

```
<ngx-datatable-group-header *ngIf="groupRowsBy" >
    <ng-template let-group="group" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-group-header-template>
        <span>
            <button (click)="showStatus(group)">{{group.key}}</button>
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-group-header>
```

I tried using `<ng-content></ng-content>` in table.component.ts and pass above template from status.component.ts

But it does not work. Can anyone please suggest how to pass this template?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass template of your status component to tablet component  you can declare your tablet component

You will declare you tablet component html like this 
You can put all the tablet template here and where ever you want to insert the status template you will put

Once your tablet component is setup you can pass your status template to it like this

```
<tablet-component></tablet-component>
```

Here you will put the status template inside the tablet component tab

Comment: I can't see anything under like this, most likely you may have missed the formatting